# Crop small file fill with intervention image

Tags: php, image, crop

Have a way to fill black area of my croped png with transparency, using intervention image?

```
 $data = file_get_contents("php://input"); 

    $img = Image::make($data);

    $path = sprintf("%/data/%s/img",public_path(),Auth::user()->account_id);

    @mkdir($path,0775,true);

    $img->crop(350, 150)->encode('png', 90)->save(sprintf("%s/logo.png",$path));
```

[image: Original]

[image: Croped image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with **trim** method!

Solution:

```
$img->crop(350, 150)->encode('png', 90)->trim()->save(sprintf("%s/logo.png",$path));
```